# How can i show date & time in the X Axis (domain axis) of the graph

Tags: androidplot

I have a graph in which i want to show Date-Time in the X Axis and some values in the Y Axis.

I am wondering how I can show the date and time on the X Axis.
The Format in which i want to show is: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`

My X Axis Data is :

```
Number[] xaxisSeries = {2407141120,2507141220,2607141640,2707141850,2807142027,2907142333};

plot.setDomainValueFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy hh:mm"));
```

But its not showing the correct values.

Please help me how should i show the Date-Time on my X Axis of the Graph

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me, based on [this example](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/TimeSeriesActivity.java). In my case, I wanted to show time only, and the x values were millis since the epoch.

```
mGraphView.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM)
        .setFormat(new Format() {
            private final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();

            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj,
                                       @NonNull StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                                       @NonNull FieldPosition pos) {
                Number timestamp = (Number) obj;
                return dateFormat.format(timestamp, toAppendTo, pos);
            }

            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, @NonNull ParsePosition pos) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: in my case always obj in format method shows value as -1. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

[There's a tutorial on androidplot.com](http://androidplot.com/docs/how-to-plot-against-time/) that describes the process.  Additionally, [here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919611/time-series-data-not-being-interpreted-properly) which includes another example of how it's done.